# Display process name using ps

Tags: ps

I am currently using this command to get some information about some specific processes:

```
ps -C beam.smp -o pid,user:20,%cpu,%mem,args
```

As I use it for two process names, I would like to do it in one command in order to get a snapshot. Like that:

```
ps -C beam.smp,docker -o pid,user:20,%cpu,%mem,args
```

The problem is that the output does not display a specific column with `beam.smp` or `docker`, which would be really useful for me. How could I get a new line in my output showing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `comm` format specifier:

```
ps -C beam.smp,docker -o pid,user:20,%cpu,%mem,comm,args
```

This shows the command name, which is exactly what you're filtering on with the `-C` selector.